# setuptools find_packages returns empty list

Tags: python, setuptools

When I try to install my package, it doesn't install anything. When I execute `find_packages` manually, it returns an empty list.

Here is my setup.py file:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('README.md') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    ...

    packages=find_packages(),
    python_requires='>=3.6',

    ...
)
```

My directory structure is

```
hackathon-base
|- hackathon
   |- __main__.py
   |- dir1
   |- dir2
|- setup.py
```

Comment: Not enough info. Please show your directory structure. Even better show your VCS repository.

Comment: ok, I've updated the answer to include the basic directory structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find_packages` internally searchs for `__init__.py` under the directories/folders

Create an empty `__init__.py` then re run `find_packages`

Go through the tutorial [here](https://godatadriven.com/blog/a-practical-guide-to-using-setup-py/)